# Nopoc Execute() method returns -1

Tags: npoco

Iam trying to pass table valued parameter to Stored procedure using NPoco

```
{var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter
        {
            SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Structured,
            ParameterName="@MetricInfoTableType",
            SqlValue=table,
            TypeName="dbo.InfoTableType"
        }
    };

    cdc.Execute("[dbo].[usp_Rules_INS]", parameters);   
}
```

then Iam geting return type is -1

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this

```
cdc.Execute(";EXEC [dbo].[usp_Rules_INS] @@MetricInfoTableType = @0", parameters);
```

Comment: Could you please expand on why this would work? I'm experiencing the same issue and I can't seem to find out why. In one case I run a script with a stored procedure and get back rows affected. e.g. Update User returns 0 or 1. In another case I Insert Order and Order Line Item and Order Address, which in the stored procedure should return back around 4, but it returns back -1. According to our DBA it should return back 0 for the "exit status code though". I find this inconsistency without documentation to be hard to know when to rollback -- do you know where I can find more information on this?

Comment: If you are expecting a return value you want to use ExecuteScalar<>. int RC = Database.ExecuteScalar<int>(";EXEC [dbo].[usp_Rules_INS] @@MetricInfoTableType = @0", parameters);

Comment: I'm not expecting a return value, I'm expecting a return code. When you execute a command in SQL it returns @@ERROR = 0. When I run db.Execute(";Exec proc @@param = @param") I sometimes get -1, and sometimes get 1 and I'm struggling with the inconsistency. Do you know where I can find the exit code reason?